# Image for product not showing on category page but it showing on product page

Tags: magento2, product-images

Magento CE 2.3.2

Uploaded new image and set base, small and thumbnail that image save product navigate on category page for that product image not showing and open image path in new tab , image not found but
when open product in new tab, it showing that image on product detail page. I also open path in new tab it working and showing image. compare both category page product image path and product page image path both are same.

So for I have  done

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

> php bin/magento s:d:c

> php bin/magento s:s:d

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

> chmod  -R 777 pub/ var/

Comment: you are missing the deploy command. I would do this sequence:

bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento catalog:images:resize
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: I have done with all mentioned commands except bin/magento catalog:images:resize this command shows image does not exist in some directories.

Comment: Issue is resolved now there was missing .htaccess file inside pub/media

Comment: great! thanks for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the deploy command. I would do this sequence:

- bin/magento setup:upgrade
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- bin/magento setup:di:compile
- bin/magento indexer:reindex
- bin/magento catalog:images:resize
- bin/magento cache:flush
- bin/magento cache:clean

Please note that deploy command shall include the languages your website has on all language folders... like en_US -f if in English, pt_BR -f if in portuguese